# Validar formulas

Tags: javascript, c#, validación

Tengo un arreglo de operadores `[*, -, +, %]` y otro arreglo para variables `[FE, GE, PRD, RON]`. En un input text, el usuario con ambos arreglos puede crear formulas es decir, FE+GE*RON por ejemplo.

¿Cómo puedo validar que la fórmula esté bien armada con operadores y variables de ambos arreglos?

Si alguien tiene una sugerencia puede ser con JavaScript o C#

De antemano, muchas gracias

Comment: ¿cual es tu problema? osea, que es lo que no sabes hacer de lo que planteas, porque va desde obtener el valor de una variable hasta evaluar una ecuación en tiempo de ejecución

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un replace de los simbolos para despues poder hacer un split y despues tomar todo menos lo de tu arreglo

```
var arregloVariables = new string[] { "FE", "GE", "PRD", "RON" };
        var formula = "FE+GE*RONI";
        var stringSinoperadores = formula.Replace('*', ',').Replace('-', ',').Replace('+', ',').Replace('%', ',');
        var split = stringSinoperadores.Split(',');
        var res = split.Except(arregloVariables);

        Console.WriteLine(res.Any() ? "Formula incorrecta" : "Formula correcta");
```